# Best practice for TouchID authentification and keychain

Tags: ios, security, keychain, touch-id

I have written an app with support for member accounts with ordinary username and password.

Now I wanted to implement TouchID for convenience. But I stumbled at the point where my login token expires ( my server gives users such a token to be used for some time after a successful login until this token itself expires): In order to logging in the iser via TouchID (without him typing in his credentials once agaim), I need to store that information on the phone.

Looks like the keychain is the tech to use for that. Bit then I asked myself: If the credentials lie in this keychain, where‘s the purpose for using ToichID at all? Why not just using the stored credentials and do a silent login in the background?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Apps typically use TouchID to verify that the person launching the app is a device “owner” before providing access to information.

For example, I may give my unlocked phone to someone so that they can make a call. If they launch my banking app, they cannot access my account information without providing a valid fingerprint or the passcode even though the secrets that the app needs are aleady in the keychain.

You need to assess the sensitivity of the information provided by your app and determine how often (if at all) you need the user to provide a TouchID credential.